# How can I remove pictures from contacts to save space?

Tags: contacts, internal-storage

I am desperate for app space on my HTC Desire. When looking at what I use app storage for, i can see that 12 mb (since this question was first asked this has grown to 16 mb) is spent on contacts. This is probably because I sync contacts with Facebook, and therefore have pictures of a lot of contacts. Now, to save space, I would like to delete these pictures. How can I do that?

Comment: I find that this data usage grows with time even when you aren't adding many contacts. Therefore, I think it includes information like latest status updates (from facebook, twitter, etc.) So the picture delete may not help...

Answer (score 2):

On my phone I have an option to delete bulk contact pictures when I push the menu button when in my contacts. However this is using a custom rom on an htc desire hd. I'm pretty sure if you're still running sense you can choose to uncheck the sync with facebook option, along with a delete contact picture option. If worse comes to worst then you can always manually delete the pictures of each contact after you uncheck the sync with facebook option.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow managed to do this. I am not quite sure how, but I created a fake Facebook profile with no friends (hence no pictures to sync). I then tried to set up the syncing of contacts with this Facebook profile. I got an error message that the service was unavailable when trying to log into this profile, and suddenly all the pictures disappeared from my contacts! I am now down on using 9 MB on contacts instead of 16 mb.